# tastypie -- OAuthAuthentication -- python-oauth2 import issue

Tags: tastypie

I am wishing to use OAuthAuthentication in tastypie. In my ModelResource, I do:
(showing only the relevant portion)

```
`from tastypie.authentication import OAuthAuthentication
class FooResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        authentication = OAuthAuthentication()`
```

And I get an error saying:
The 'python-oauth2' package could not be imported. It is required for use with the 'OAuthAuthentication' class.

Before this, I did a pip install of python-oauth(below), but subsequently, it continues the complaint above. Do I need to do anything else in my resource or anywhere else to explicitly import this?

```
`pip install -r http://code.daaku.org/python-oauth/reqs
Obtaining urlencoding from git+git://github.com/nshah/python-urlencoding.git#egg=urlencoding (from -r http://code.daaku.org/python-oauth/reqs (line 1))
  Cloning git://github.com/nshah/python-urlencoding.git to ./src/urlencoding
  Running setup.py egg_info for package urlencoding
Obtaining oauth from git+git://github.com/nshah/python-oauth.git#egg=oauth (from -r http://code.daaku.org/python-oauth/reqs (line 2))
  Cloning git://github.com/nshah/python-oauth.git to ./src/oauth
  Running setup.py egg_info for package oauth
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): distribute in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from urlencoding->-r http://code.daaku.org/python-oauth/reqs (line 1))
Downloading/unpacking setuptools-git (from urlencoding->-r http://code.daaku.org/python-oauth/reqs (line 1))
  Downloading setuptools-git-0.4.2.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package setuptools-git
Installing collected packages: urlencoding, oauth, setuptools-git
  Running setup.py develop for urlencoding
    Creating /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/urlencoding.egg-link (link to .)
    Adding urlencoding 0.0.1 to easy-install.pth file

    Installed /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tastypie/src/urlencoding
  Running setup.py develop for oauth
    Creating /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/oauth.egg-link (link to .)
    Adding oauth 0.0.1 to easy-install.pth file

    Installed /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tastypie/src/oauth
  Running setup.py install for setuptools-git
Successfully installed urlencoding oauth setuptools-git
Cleaning up...`
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're installing "python-oauth" instead of "python-oauth2". The error clearly states that. To solve this issue, you should simply install "python-oauth2" which is a different library from "python-oauth".

Try this:

```
pip install oauth2
```